# Is there a way to get the feature name during runtime using cucumber + ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

In my cucumber+watir+ruby tests I have the results of each going to results.html. I would like to use the feature name instead.

Something like:

```
<%= feature_name %>.html
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
scenario.feature.name 
scenario.scenario_outline.feature.name
```

This should get you the name

Comment: Can this be used in the profile? I am setting the output file name in cucumber.yml. Thanks!